# Access Django model instance in ModelForm's FormField definions

Tags: django, django-forms, olwidget

in one of my admin forms, I override a model form field (`location`) in order to use a different, map specific form field (`olwidget`). This MapField should include a layer (`InfoLayerField`) that displays all *other* model instances but the one that is being edited at the moment. Right now, it displays *all* the model instances (see `MyModel.objects.all()`) which means, if a model is edited the current location is displayed twice.

In order to achieve this, I'd have to exclude the current edited model instance from the QuerySet used in `InfoLayerField` (something like `MyModel.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)`). But since form fields are defined as static variables, I can't access `self.instance`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)


# admin.py
from olwidget.fields import MapField, EditableLayerField, InfoLayerField
from olwidget.utils import get_ewkt

class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    location = MapField([
        EditableLayerField({
            'geometry': 'point',
            'name': 'location',
        }),
        InfoLayerField(
            [(get_ewkt(m.location), m.name) for m in MyModel.objects.all() if m.location ], {
                'geometry': 'point',
                'name': 'other locations',
                'cluster': True,
                'cluster_display': 'list',
            }
        )
    ])

class MyModelOlwidgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, GeoModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm

...
```

Thanks for any hint's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to override the `__init__` on your form:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        qs = MyModel.objects.exclude(pk = self.instance.pk) #grab instance.pk here
        self.fields['location'] = MapField([
            EditableLayerField({
                'geometry': 'point',
                'name': 'location',
            }),
            InfoLayerField(
                [(get_ewkt(m.location), m.name) for m in qs if m.location ], {
                    'geometry': 'point',
                    'name': 'other locations',
                    'cluster': True,
                    'cluster_display': 'list',
                }
            )
        ])
```